# FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Failed to fetch resource from https ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
W/Logged in: signInWithCredential
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Failed to fetch resource from https ]
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbix.zzcb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf.zzcc(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbja$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Getting above logs while using facebook authentication in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your firebase authorisation panel and activate authorisation for Email/password.

Comment: Temporarily try the "anonymously" / guest sign in. I had the same problem as this and it worked for me.

Comment: also try the Facebook sign in too

Comment: I provided you link to step you through. I imagine you missed an important step  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem

Add `public_profile` in the permission like this:-

`fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");`